# Is multiprocessing.Queue generic or not (pyright)?

Tags: python, python-typing, pyright

I started using pyright recently (over mypy) and it's finding a lot of issues that weren't coming up with mypy. For example

```py
from multiprocessing import Queue

queue: Queue = Queue()  # Type of "queue" is "Queue[Unknown]" [reportUnknownVariableType]
```

This is surprising to me because `multiprocessing.Queue` doesn't appear to have a generic type argument when I inspect the source (python 3.9). Is this pyright making standard library types generic as a "feature" or am I just wrong about Queue somehow?

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/885

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a pyright feature and you're not wrong about how Queue works, rather, it's the result of the [typeshed](https://github.com/python/typeshed/blob/main/stdlib/multiprocessing/queues.pyi) of `multiprocessing.Queue` having a generic argument, but the [standard library](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/multiprocessing/queues.py) implementation not having it.

In general type checkers will look at the `.pyi` files over the `.py` files, and use those for any information. Since the standard library does not have type hints in any of the .py files, it is then expected that the generic argument only shows up in the typeshed.

Because the standard library implementation of Queue does not have this generic argument, you need a `from __future__ import annotations` import to be able to use the `Queue[str]` from typeshed. The exact error you're currently getting is the type checker reporting that you did not do that, and kept it as an unspecified `Queue` instead. This is the same error you would get if you annotated a function with `List`

Lastly, as pointed out in the [comments](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/885) to your post, this not working properly with pyright (e.g. it giving a different error when you typehint with just `Queue`) is (or at least was, [it is said to be fixed now](https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/issues/885#issuecomment-663790134)) indeed a bug, but I don't think that is related to your issue.

Comment: Incredible technical insight! While I may not be the one who initially encountered this problem, stumbling upon your answer was a stroke of luck. Your deep technical explanation showcases a profound understanding of the intricacies involved, and it's evident that you've not only solved the problem at hand but also provided a valuable resource for others facing similar challenges. A big thank you for sharing your expertise with the community!

Comment: @enzo Did I misunderstand the question? Your sarcasm suggests to me that I did. :P

Comment: No, it's a great answer indeed. Don't worry! Sorry if it seemed like sarcarm.

Comment: Are you saying that the most correct thing to do would be to include a generic parameter like `Queue[str]` and include the `__future__` import to make sure it doesn't break the python interpreter? Also, `annotations` is a very weird name to import to fix a generic parameter problem. Can you also compare it to doing `queue: "Queue[str]"`?

Comment: @AnthonyNaddeo that's indeed my idea. On your current level of warnings with pyright, that is the "correct" way to do it, if I understand correctly.

And, indeed, the `annotations` import is there to make the python interpreter take in all the type arguments as strings. I simply find that cleaner than annotating with `"Queue[str]"`.